# How can I return to nohup after logout?

Tags: gnu-screen, aix, nohup

I'm working on an AIX and cannot install screen but want to use its capabilities. Basically I want to be able to run a session (maybe logout), then the same user but logged in again to be able to get it back to the foreground.

I send a job to the background and login with the same user on the machine and jobs does not show it so I can get it back in fg.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to install screen then don't, your choices are `dtach`, `tmux` and `byobu`. No magical fairy will let you do what these programs do without installing something.

Answer (score 1):

Other options would be to use the console and some kind of terminal concentrator.  Or start up an xvfb and run a terminal inside of it, attaching via vnc.  But screen is your best bet, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Login from a workstation which will remain online, and then use the `portmir` command to attach to that running process. You won't have scrollback, but you can take over the terminal.

Comment: You could log the terminal with the "script" command to a file if you need scrollback. Of course, if you nohup that's what nohup.out is for.